# wxWidget 3.1 self build and install causes link issue: undefined reference to `wxGLCanvasX11::~wxGLCanvasX11()'

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, kali-linux

I use Kali Linux , and since the package library `libwxgtk3.1-gtk3-dev` doesn't exist yet, I need to build the code from the Github repository https://github.com/wxWidgets.
As documented, I did:

```
mkdir build_gtk
cd build_gtk
../configure
make
su <type root password>
make install
ldconfig
```

Afterwards, I compile my project code, which has been successfully built on Ubuntu 21.04.
However, I got these errors, that the compiler cannot link `wxGLCanvasX11`.

```
[  4%] Linking CXX executable simulator
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/...: in function `wxGLCanvas::~wxGLCanvas()':
/home/..../wxWidgets/include/wx-3.1/wx/gtk/glcanvas.h:20: undefined reference to `wxGLCanvasX11::~wxGLCanvasX11()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/....: undefined reference to `wxGLCanvasX11::IsShownOnScreen() const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/....: undefined reference to `wxGLCanvasX11::IsShownOnScreen() const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/.....cc.o:(...): undefined reference to `wxGLCanvasX11::SwapBuffers()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this?

I built the gtk version, but why my code want the x11 version? Why does it work on Ubuntu?

Comment: @ywiyago, when you were building the library, did it give you any warnings? Can you open `config.log` file and see if there was a warning? I believe you got one and you should install OpenGL libraries on Kali, then kill wxWidgets build, re-run configure and make and rebuild your software.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for these errors is that you're simply not linking with `libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.1.so` containing these symbols. As you're using CMake, you're probably using `find_package(wxWidgets)`, in which case you must list "gl" in its `COMPONENTS` parameter.